# OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 482112 free bytes and 470KB until OOM?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i want to make images backup because of this i use sqlite DataBase for storing images my code is worked fine when i put 10 to 12 images but after that it shows OutOfMemoryError . i use android:largeHeap="true" it increase some amount of memory but this is not sufficient for my work.how can i solve this??please help me guys.

this is my code:

```
 if(data==null){
                   Uri uri = data.getData();


                  try {

                      InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                      BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                      byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();

                      DataBase dataBase=new DataBase(getBaseContext());
                      dataBase.insertImage(bArray);
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"single item  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Comment: Store images in memory and save only their path in sqlite.

Comment: @Sharj u mean in file??

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the image is very large. You can save the image with paint in Jpg and reduce in this way the size. Try with different dimensions until one of them works.

Comment: Definitely a good point here.  "Damn the (Apple) retina displays," be sure that your images "look good *enough,"* but no better.  There's definitely a point of diminishing returns, especially when you're dealing with a display that's smaller than a postcard.  A highly compressed, relatively small JPG image might easily be "quite good enough."

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the code that *surrounds* this snippet, i.e. "how the retrieved data is managed."  For instance, you might well find it impossible(!) to hold "10 or 12 images" in memory at the same time ... *and-d-d* each device will be different!  (You, as a developer, naturally buy a "decked out" device, while your Actual Customer bought her phone at the grocery store.)  You're going to have to design some kind of scheme that stores only recently-retrieved images in memory.

One possible strategy is to store these images in objects that are held in a collection that has "weak references" to the objects.  If the memory manager is short of memory, it can harvest those objects.  (A good discussion of this can be found at http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-weak-reference/ .)  Your code must be prepared to check if the object has been reaped, but it's a fairly manageable way to handle not knowing how much memory you do have.

*Also,* your code must be **graceful** if it gets thrown an "out of memory" exception!  Maybe in that case it *voluntarily* throws-away the oldest entry in its container, then tries the operation again.  And, so on.  In the mobile world, you don't have the luxury of "unlimited *virtual* memory."  Memory is a *real* resource.